# Not been able to set focus to my <ion-input> as i enter the page

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want focus to be set on my `<ion-input>` as I enter the page

This is my typescript code:

```
import { Component, Input, ViewChild,ElementRef,Renderer } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, PopoverController, NavParams, ViewController, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-comments',
  templateUrl: 'comments.html'
})
export class CommentsParentPage {
    @ViewChild('input') myInput;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private renderer: Renderer, 
                private elementRef: ElementRef, public modalCtrl: ModalController) {
    }

    ionViewLoaded() {

       setTimeout(() => {
          let element = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
          this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(element, 'focus', []);
       },150);
    }

}
```

And this is what i have done with my `html` file:

```
 <ion-item>
      <ion-input set-focuser type="text" placeholder="Write Your Comments" [(ngModel)]="addComment"></ion-input>

    </ion-item>
```

Whenever I enter this page of my application, I would like the keyboard to be opened and focus to be set on `ion-input`

My `config.xml` includes:

```
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
```

> package.json

```
 {
  "name": "sample app",
  "author": "",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic/cloud-angular": "^0.10.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.7",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.1.0",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^2.0.14",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "ionic-gallery-modal": "0.0.7",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.11",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.0.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage",
    "cordova-plugin-x-toast",
    "cordova-plugin-camera",
    "cordova-plugin-compat",
    "cordova-plugin-image-picker",
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic",
    {
      "id": "phonegap-plugin-push",
      "locator": "phonegap-plugin-push",
      "variables": {
        "SENDER_ID": "461076790064"
      }
    },
    "cordova-plugin-contacts",
    "ionic-plugin-deploy",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing",
    {
      "locator": "https://github.com/napolitano/cordova-plugin-intent",
      "id": "com.napolitano.cordova.plugin.intent"
    },
    "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation",
    "cordova-plugin-file",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    {
      "platform": "android",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "android"
    }
  ],
  "description": "ionic2: An Ionic project"
}
```

Comment: `this.myInput.setFocus()` doesnt work?

Comment: no , thats why i used 
 let element = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
    this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(element, 'focus', []);

Comment: do you get any errors

Comment: no , no errors , it just doesn't work

Comment: Inside your `setTimeout` handler, you can try: (1) `this.myInput.nativeElement.focus();` or (2) `element.focus();`. And maybe increase the timeout to 1000 ms for testing.

Answer (score 11):

use ngAfterViewChecked:

See plnkr [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/1UzJDV?p=preview)

```
import { Component, Input, ViewChild,ElementRef,Renderer, AfterViewChecked,ChangeDetectorRef  } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, PopoverController, NavParams, ViewController, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-comments',
  templateUrl: 'comments.html'
})

export class CommentsParentPage implements AfterViewChecked {
@ViewChild('input') myInput;

needsFocus: boolean;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private renderer: Renderer, 
            private elementRef: ElementRef, public modalCtrl: ModalController, 
            private _changeDetectionRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
}

ionViewDidEnter() {

   this.needsFocus = true;
}

public ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    if (this.needsFocus) {
        this.needsFocus = false;
        this.myInput.setFocus();
        this._changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: @devanshsadhotra My bad, you should set the boolean true in ionViewDidEnter. I've updated the example and added a Plnkr to showcase

Comment: also be sure to identify the input in your html (<ion-input #input ..)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `Directive` as shown below.Hope code is self-explanatory.If you have any issue please comment below.

Play with [**Git Repo code**](https://github.com/Sampath-Lokuge/SetFocuser).

You can View this on **Ionic View**: **Id = F5F367AE**

**Note:** Just tap `My Page`.

[image]

***set-focuser.ts***

```
import { Directive, Renderer, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';

@Directive({
  selector: '[set-focuser]' // Attribute selector
})
export class SetFocuser {

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer, private elementRef: ElementRef, public keyboard: Keyboard) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const element = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
    // to delay 
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(element, 'focus', []);
      this.keyboard.show();
    }, 500);
  }

}
```

***.html***

```
 <ion-input set-focuser type="text"></ion-input>
```

***app.module.ts***

```
import { SetFocuser } from "../components/set-focuser/set-focuser";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
     SetFocuser,
  ],
```

***Issues on your package.json***

1. You have to remove `"ionic-native": "2.2.11",` module.
2. Use   `"@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.4",` instead of  `"@ionic/app-scripts": "1.0.0",`
3. After the above changes run `npm i`

This is the [**official package.json file**](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app/blob/master/package.json).

Comment: did the same as per your repo , installed ionic native keyboard plugin , still it did not work

Comment: Can you show your code with `package.json` file? Please put that on your original post.

Comment: Or can you put a lightweight version of your implementation on Git repo? I'll make it works.

Comment: are we supposed to import our set-focuser.ts into app.module.ts

Comment: Yes, as under `declarations`.Please see my git repo (`app.module.ts`).

Comment: tried as u did , still facing no change , it's not focusing

Comment: It seems where you have an issue on your code.can you put a lightweight version of it into git repo? this is very easy thing to implemnt.but seems you have done something wrong where you cannot see.if it's working for me then how can't you do? put it into a git repo and let me know.

Comment: have included my package.json

Comment: due to other components of the application , i cannot make changes in package.json as it is hampering other necessary components

Comment: you just need to install your plugins again and implement your plugins as `providers`.very simple.please see the doc. http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic, but I faced a similar issue (in my case there was an error: 'setFocus is not a function'. My solution may help someone in the future (Ionic v5).

In this case I generated a component instead of a page, so I didn't have a module.ts file for the component. I had to add the component to the parent page's declarations.

```
declarations: [
    MyModalComponent
]
```

Then in the component's typescript file, added the following lines and it worked as intended:

```
@ViewChild('myInputsReference', {static: false}) inputEl: IonInput;

ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.setFocusOnInput();
}

setFocusOnInput() {
    setTimeout(_ => { this.inputEl.setFocus()}, 200);
}
```

Comment: This setTimeout approach solved my problem. But I had to use focus() instead of setFocus()

Comment: well but setTimeout is not really a good solution is it? I mean how do you know that 200ms is enough? What if the user has a shitty slow phone, then it might be too soon?

Answer (score -2):

You can try simple method.

```
 <div ng-init="getfocus()">
   <ion-input id="myAnchor" type="text" placeholder="Write Your Comments"/>
</div>
```

In js file call a function with ng-init

```
function getfocus() {
   document.getElementById("myAnchor").focus();
}
```

Hope this code will help you.if you get any error please comment.

Comment: this is disabling my ion input